# Rate limit the amount of content throughout a forEach iteration

Tags: javascript, html, performance, loops, sockets

***Preamble:***

I'm in progress of developing a site where users can send messages to each other. However, when
a user joins the site, it loads in the messages, but when there are too many messages stored, it slows down performance and takes several seconds to load each message in the array.

I have an array of messages sent by all users, however, when a user opens the site, a `forEach` loop will iterate throughout every message in the messages array and would possibly crash the user's device or drop performance.

Instead, I am asking how could I get about 20 - 30 messages to load at once, then have a `setInterval` which loads 20 - 30 more messages every 10 seconds or whenever a user scrolls to read more.

I have currently tried as my current code, but with 100s, 1000s of items to send within the array, it gets slow:

```
messages.forEach(sent => {
    io.to(user.id).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, sent));
})
```

And just to clarify, the messages array is simply looks like,

```
messages = ['<div class="message">Username, text, date </div>', '<div class="message">Username, text, date </div>']
```

and so on, each time when a user sends a message, it pushes to the array.

I've tried reversing the array and sending the last 10 messages, however it just makes things worse and confuses me. Could anyone please provide some help?

Comment: Do you really need to send the entire history of the conversation to each user as and when he/she joins the room? Usually one would expect a limited subset of the conversation to be available - perhaps the last 20 items etc rather than potentially thousands...

Comment: Yes, you've just explained what my intention is, I just don't know how to do that @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: So - you do NOT want to send the entire conversation just a portion of it?

Comment: Exactly, as you said, load 20 items as a portion of all the total messages. When a user opens the page, it would be so much better to load only a few messages a time, then load the rest at a later point.

Comment: Check out array.slice(). There are lots of q/a's here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually shown what you tried, so a possible starting point:

```
// get first 10.
messages.slice(0, 10).forEach(sent => {
    io.to(user.id).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, sent));
}) 

// get last 10.
messages.reverse().slice(0, 10).forEach(sent => {
    io.to(user.id).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, sent));
})
```